# Astronauts with oversensitive skin after returning from space

Tags: astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle

I have heard that some astronaut (maybe Scott Kelly) complained about itchy, sensitive skin after returning from space. Is it true? After growing 2 inches, now he can't sleep on a bed and wear Earth clothes and walk.

Comment: Was Scott Kelly.  You experience pressure to your skin each day - walking, sleeping, sitting. Each movement of your body changes direction of gravity pull to your soft tissues. Not only pressure but gravity stretching that skin each day each moment. If you will do experiment like laying in bed for 1-3weeks - you may notice some changes in knees after that, walking may be not so much comfortable. Depends on age too, I think for more younger at growing age - more noticeable.